# How Would I fix the player collision so they aren't constantly getting stuck

Tags: java, 2d, game-development

I am making my first 2d game and when i move up and collide with a tile it stops and i can still move left and right but it is difficult to move through a doorway.

the image below shows where the player gets stuck they cant move right or down they also can't move up but that is intended

Sorry if i left something important out this is my first time posting a question.

- Edit

to try to clarify
my collision box is set a bit smaller than my player so that the player will overlap the wall tiles a bit so when attempting to walk through a doorway to the right if the top of the player collision Box collides with the bottom of the tiles collision box it does stop the player from moving up but if the player tries to keep moving right the player would be stopped

[an image of where the player is getting stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32IEo.png)

- CollisionHandler.java (Handles all collisions)

```
package game.handlers;

import game.GamePanel;
import game.entities.Entity;

import game.items.Item;
import game.items.objects.*;
import game.items.misc.*;

public class CollisionHandler
{
    GamePanel gp;

    public CollisionHandler(GamePanel gp)
    {
        this.gp = gp;
    }

    public void checkTile(Entity entity)
    {
        int entityLeftWorldX = entity.worldX + entity.collisionBox.x;
        int entityRightWorldX = entity.worldX + entity.collisionBox.x + entity.collisionBox.width;
        int entityTopWorldY = entity.worldY + entity.collisionBox.y;
        int entityBottemWorldY = entity.worldY + entity.collisionBox.y + entity.collisionBox.height;

        int entityLeftCol = entityLeftWorldX / gp.tileSize;
        int entityRightCol = entityRightWorldX / gp.tileSize;
        int entityTopRow = entityTopWorldY / gp.tileSize;
        int entityBottemRow = entityBottemWorldY / gp.tileSize;

        int tileNum1, tileNum2;
        
        switch(entity.direction)
        {
            case "up":
                entityTopRow = (entityTopWorldY - entity.speed) / gp.tileSize;
                tileNum1 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityLeftCol] [entityTopRow];
                tileNum2 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityRightCol] [entityBottemRow];

                if(gp.tm.tile[tileNum1].hasCollision || gp.tm.tile[tileNum2].hasCollision)
                {
                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                }

                break;
            case "down":
                entityBottemRow = (entityBottemWorldY + entity.speed) / gp.tileSize;
                tileNum1 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityLeftCol] [entityTopRow];
                tileNum2 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityRightCol] [entityBottemRow];

                if(gp.tm.tile[tileNum1].hasCollision || gp.tm.tile[tileNum2].hasCollision)
                {
                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                }

                break;
            case "left":
                entityLeftCol = (entityLeftWorldX - entity.speed) / gp.tileSize;
                tileNum1 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityLeftCol] [entityTopRow];
                tileNum2 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityRightCol] [entityBottemRow];

                if(gp.tm.tile[tileNum1].hasCollision || gp.tm.tile[tileNum2].hasCollision)
                {
                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                }

                break;
            case "right":
                entityRightCol = (entityRightWorldX + entity.speed) / gp.tileSize;
                tileNum1 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityLeftCol] [entityTopRow];
                tileNum2 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityRightCol] [entityBottemRow];

                if(gp.tm.tile[tileNum1].hasCollision || gp.tm.tile[tileNum2].hasCollision)
                {
                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                }
                
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public int checkItem(Entity entity, boolean player)
    {
        int index = 999;

        for(Item item: gp.items)
        {
            if(item != null)
            {
                entity.collisionBox.x = entity.worldX + entity.collisionBox.x;
                entity.collisionBox.y = entity.worldY + entity.collisionBox.y;

                item.collisionBox.x = item.worldX + item.collisionBox.x;
                item.collisionBox.y = item.worldY + item.collisionBox.y;

                switch(entity.direction)
                {
                    case "up":
                        entity.collisionBox.y -= entity.speed;
                        if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                        {
                            if(item.hasCollision)
                            {
                                entity.collisionOn = true;
                            }
                            if(player)
                            {
                                index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                            }
                        
                        }
                        break;
                    case "down":
                        entity.collisionBox.y += entity.speed;
                        if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                        {
                           if(item.hasCollision)
                            {
                                entity.collisionOn = true;
                            }
                            if(player)
                            {
                                index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "left":
                        entity.collisionBox.x -= entity.speed;
                        if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                        {
                            if(item.hasCollision)
                            {
                                entity.collisionOn = true;
                            }
                            if(player)
                            {
                                index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        entity.collisionBox.x += entity.speed;
                        if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                        {
                            if(item.hasCollision)
                            {
                                entity.collisionOn = true;
                            }
                            if(player)
                            {
                                index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                /*switch(entity.direction)
                {
                    case "up":
                        entity.collisionBox.y -= entity.speed;
                        if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                        {
                            if(item instanceof SObject)
                            {
                                SObject object = (SObject)item;
                                object.interact(gp);

                                if(item.hasCollision)
                                {
                                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                                }
                                if(player)
                                {
                                    index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                if(item.hasCollision)
                                {
                                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                                }
                                if(player)
                                {
                                    index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                                }
                            }
                        
                        }
                        break;
                    case "down":
                        entity.collisionBox.y += entity.speed;
                        if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                        {
                            if(item instanceof SObject)
                            {
                                SObject object = (SObject)item;
                                object.interact(gp);

                                if(item.hasCollision)
                                {
                                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                                }
                                if(player)
                                {
                                    index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                if(item.hasCollision)
                                {
                                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                                }
                                if(player)
                                {
                                    index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "left":
                        entity.collisionBox.x -= entity.speed;
                        if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                        {
                            if(item instanceof SObject)
                            {
                                SObject object = (SObject)item;
                                object.interact(gp);

                                if(item.hasCollision)
                                {
                                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                                }
                                if(player)
                                {
                                    index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                if(item.hasCollision)
                                {
                                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                                }
                                if(player)
                                {
                                    index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        entity.collisionBox.x += entity.speed;
                        if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                        {
                            if(item instanceof SObject)
                            {
                                SObject object = (SObject)item;
                                object.interact(gp);

                                if(item.hasCollision)
                                {
                                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                                }
                                if(player)
                                {
                                    index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                if(item.hasCollision)
                                {
                                    entity.collisionOn = true;
                                }
                                if(player)
                                {
                                    index = gp.items.indexOf(item);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }*/
                entity.collisionBox.x = entity.defaultCollisionBoxX;
                entity.collisionBox.y = entity.defaultCollisionBoxY;

                item.collisionBox.x = item.defaultCollisionBoxX;
                item.collisionBox.y = item.defaultCollisionBoxY;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }

    public void interact(Entity entity, int index)
    {
        Item item = gp.items.get(index);
                
        if(item != null)
        {
            entity.collisionBox.x = entity.worldX + entity.collisionBox.x;
            entity.collisionBox.y = entity.worldY + entity.collisionBox.y;

            item.collisionBox.x = item.worldX + item.collisionBox.x;
            item.collisionBox.y = item.worldY + item.collisionBox.y;

            switch(entity.direction)
            {
                case "up":
                    entity.collisionBox.y -= entity.speed;
                    if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                    {
                        if(item.hasCollision)
                        {
                            entity.collisionOn = true;
                        }
                    
                    }
                    break;
                case "down":
                    entity.collisionBox.y += entity.speed;
                    if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                    {
                        if(item.hasCollision)
                        {
                            entity.collisionOn = true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "left":
                    entity.collisionBox.x -= entity.speed;
                    if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                    {
                        if(item.hasCollision)
                        {
                            entity.collisionOn = true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "right":
                    entity.collisionBox.x += entity.speed;
                    if(entity.collisionBox.intersects(item.collisionBox))
                    {
                        if(item.hasCollision)
                        {
                            entity.collisionOn = true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            entity.collisionBox.x = entity.defaultCollisionBoxX;
            entity.collisionBox.y = entity.defaultCollisionBoxY;

            item.collisionBox.x = item.defaultCollisionBoxX;
            item.collisionBox.y = item.defaultCollisionBoxY;
        }
    }
}
```

- Entity.java (the class i extend all other entities from player, enemies, npcs, exc...)

```
package game.entities;

import game.util.Inventory;
import game.items.Item;

import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Entity
{
    public int health;
    public int maxHealth;

    public int worldX, worldY;
    public int speed;

    public BufferedImage up1, up2, down1, down2, left1, left2, right1, right2;
    public String direction;

    public int spriteCounter = 0;
    public int spriteNumber = 1;

    public Rectangle collisionBox;
    public int defaultCollisionBoxX, defaultCollisionBoxY;
    public boolean collisionOn = false;

    public Inventory inv = new Inventory(this);

    public Item equiped;

    public ArrayList<String> diialogues = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void heal(int amountToHeal)
    {
        health += amountToHeal;
        if(health > maxHealth)
        {
            health = maxHealth;
        }
    }

    public void damage(int amountToDamage)
    {
        health -= amountToDamage;
        if(health < 0)
        {
            health = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

- Player.java (The class containing the player of the game)

```
package game.entities;

import game.handlers.KeyHandler;
import game.items.Item;
import game.items.objects.SObject;
import game.GamePanel;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Player extends Entity
{
    GamePanel gp;
    KeyHandler kh;

    public final int screenX;
    public final int screenY;

    public Player(GamePanel gp, KeyHandler kh)
    {
        this.gp = gp;
        this.kh = kh;

        screenX = gp.screenWidth/2 - (gp.tileSize/2);
        screenY = gp.screenHeight/2 - (gp.tileSize/2);

        collisionBox = new Rectangle(8, 16, 32, 32);

        defaultCollisionBoxX = collisionBox.x;
        defaultCollisionBoxY = collisionBox.y;

        worldX = gp.tileSize * 22;
        worldY = gp.tileSize * 46; //46
        
        speed = 4;

        direction = "down";

        health = 50;
        maxHealth = 100;

        getPlayerImage();
    }

    public void getPlayerImage()
    {
        try 
        {
            up1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Entities/Player/boy_up_1.png"));
            up2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Entities/Player/boy_up_2.png"));

            down1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Entities/Player/boy_down_1.png"));
            down2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Entities/Player/boy_down_2.png"));

            left1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Entities/Player/boy_left_1.png"));
            left2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Entities/Player/boy_left_2.png"));

            right1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Entities/Player/boy_right_1.png"));
            right2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Entities/Player/boy_right_2.png"));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void interactObject(int index)
    {
        if(gp.kh.ePressed)
        {
            if(index != 999)
            {
                SObject object = (SObject)gp.items.get(index);
                object.interact(gp);
            }
        }
    }

    public void pickUpItem(int index)
    {
        if(index != 999)
        {
           if(gp.items.get(index) instanceof SObject)
           {
           }
           else 
           {
                //inv.items.add(gp.items.get(index));
                gp.items.set(index, null);
           }
        }
    }

    public void interactNPC(int index)
    {}

    public void update()
    {
        if(kh.downPressed || kh.upPressed || kh.leftPressed || kh.rightPressed)
        {
            if(kh.upPressed)
            {
                direction = "up";
            }

            if(kh.downPressed)
            {
                direction = "down";
            }

            if(kh.leftPressed)
            {
                direction = "left";
            }

            if(kh.rightPressed)
            {
                direction = "right";
            }

            collisionOn = false;
            gp.ch.checkTile(this);

            int itemIndex = gp.ch.checkItem(this, true);
            pickUpItem(itemIndex);

            if(!collisionOn)
            {
                switch(direction)
                {
                    case "up":
                        worldY -= speed;
                        break;
                    case "down":
                        worldY += speed;
                        break;
                    case "left":
                        worldX -= speed;
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        worldX += speed;
                        break;
                }
            }
            
            //int objectIndex = gp.ch.checkItem(this, true);
            //interactObject(objectIndex);

            gp.kh.ePressed = false;

            spriteCounter++;
            if(spriteCounter > 12)
            {
                if(spriteNumber == 1)
                {
                    spriteNumber = 2;
                }
                else if(spriteNumber == 2)
                {
                    spriteNumber = 1;
                }
                spriteCounter = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
    {
        BufferedImage image = null;

        switch(direction)
        {
            case "up":
                if(spriteNumber == 1)
                {
                    image = up1;
                }
                else if(spriteNumber == 2)
                {
                    image = up2;
                }
                break;
            case "down":
                if(spriteNumber == 1)
                {
                    image = down1;
                }
                else if(spriteNumber == 2)
                {
                    image = down2;
                }
                break;
            case "left":
                if(spriteNumber == 1)
                {
                    image = left1;
                }
                else if(spriteNumber == 2)
                {
                    image = left2;
                }
                break;
            case "right":
                if(spriteNumber == 1)
                {
                    image = right1;
                }
                else if(spriteNumber == 2)
                {
                    image = right2;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        int x = screenX;
        int y = screenY;

        if(screenX > worldX)
        {
            x = worldX;
        }

        if(screenY > worldY)
        {
            y = worldY;
        }

        int rightOffset = gp.screenWidth - gp.player.screenX;
        if(rightOffset > gp.worldWidth - gp.player.worldX)
        {
            x = gp.screenWidth - (gp.worldWidth - worldX);
        }

        int bottemOffset = gp.screenHeight - gp.player.screenY;
        if(bottemOffset > gp.worldHeight - gp.player.worldY)
        {
            y = gp.screenHeight -(gp.worldHeight - worldY);
        }

        g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, gp.tileSize, gp.tileSize, null);
    }
}
```

- KeyHandler.java (handles all my key imputs)

```
package game.handlers;

import game.GamePanel;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener
{
    GamePanel gp;

    public boolean upPressed, leftPressed, downPressed, rightPressed;
    public boolean ePressed, enterPressed;

    private boolean u, u2, d, d2, l, r, l2, r2;

    public KeyHandler(GamePanel gp)
    {
        this.gp = gp;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int input = e.getKeyCode();

        if(gp.gameState == gp.playState)
        {
            if(input == KeyEvent.VK_W)
            {
                upPressed = true;
            }

            if(input == KeyEvent.VK_A)
            {
                leftPressed = true;
            }

            if(input == KeyEvent.VK_S)
            {
                downPressed = true;
            }

            if(input == KeyEvent.VK_D)
            {
                rightPressed = true;
            }

            //interact key
            if(input == KeyEvent.VK_E)
            {
                ePressed = true;
            }

            //Dev mode
            if(input == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            {
                if(!u)
                {
                    u = true;
                }
                else if(u)
                {
                    u2 = true;
                }

                if(u && u2)
                {
                    if(!gp.devMode)
                    {
                        gp.devMode = true;
                    }
                    else if(gp.devMode)
                    {
                        gp.devMode = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(gp.devMode)
            {
                if(input == KeyEvent.VK_T)
                {
                    gp.player.heal(5);
                }

                if(input == KeyEvent.VK_Y)
                {
                    gp.player.damage(5);
                }
            }
        }

        if(gp.gameState == gp.playState || gp.gameState == gp.pauseState)
        {
            //Toggle Pause Menu
            if(input == KeyEvent.VK_P)
            {
                if(gp.gameState == gp.playState)
                {
                    gp.gameState = gp.pauseState;
                }
                else if(gp.gameState == gp.pauseState)
                {
                    gp.gameState = gp.playState;
                }
            }
        }

        if(gp.gameState == gp.textState)
        {
            if(input == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                enterPressed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int input = e.getKeyCode();

        if(input == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        {
            upPressed = false;
        }

        if(input == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            leftPressed = false;
        }

        if(input == KeyEvent.VK_S)
        {
            downPressed = false;
        }

        if(input == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            rightPressed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help that can be given along with any suggestions

Comment: Your code could use a lot of refactoring, right now it's very hard to read through. Could you describe the problem in more details, please? Do I understand the situation correctly: you are inside a narrow corridor and want to move to the left into a big room through a door. However, you press the "up" key and get inside the upper wall and can't move anymore. Expected behavior: you press the "up" key, but the collision with the wall is detected, the player is not allowed to get inside the wall and got stuck, so you can keep going left/right through the door. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Or maybe you are in a big room to the left and trying to get into a narrow corridor to the right. You press the "right" key but the player is not aligned with the corridor, so he just got stuck in the wall to the right. It's hard to get inside the corridor because it's so narrow and you are not allowed to get into unless you are perfectly aligned with the corridor vertically?

Comment: @AlexSveshnikov so i edited the post to try and clarify what my problem is. also what do you mean by refactor and could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question about refactoring: there are many places where your code can be made much cleaner and efficient. For example, consider this part from KeyHandler.java:

```java
if(!u)
{
   u = true;
}
else if(u)
{
   u2 = true;
}

if(u && u2)
{
   if(!gp.devMode)
   {
       gp.devMode = true;
   }
   else if(gp.devMode)
   {
       gp.devMode = false;
   }
}
```

Take a look on the first if-statement. If `u` is false, you enter the first branch and set it to true. Otherwise `u` is true and you enter the second branch. In this second branch you have a test `if(u)`. But you can enter this branch only if `u` is true! It means that you don't need to check it again and it can be simplified to

```java
if (!u) {
   u = true;
} else {
   u2 = true;
}
```

Now, you can see that after execution of this if-statement the value of `u` will always be true (because it was either true from the start, or it was set to true in the first branch). Thus, it can be simplified even more:

```java
if (u) {
   u2 = true;
}
u = true;
```

After that the next if-statement follows. The condition is `if (u && u2)`. However, as we have seen just now the value of `u` at this point is always true. So the condition can be simplified to just `if (u2)`. What is inside the if-statement? The following code:

```java
if(!gp.devMode)
{
    gp.devMode = true;
}
else if(gp.devMode)
{
    gp.devMode = false;
}
```

Here you again perform the same excessive test as before with the `u` variable: there is no need for the second `if(gp.devMode)` check, because in order to get in this branch `gp.devMode` must be already true. The whole meaning of this if-statement is to toggle the value of `gp.devMode`: if it is true then set it to false and vice versa. You can achieve this with a simple assignment:

```java
gp.devMode = !gp.devMode;
```

So, the second if-statement can be reduced to just

```java
if (u2) {
   gp.devMode = !gp.devMode;
}
```

And the whole block of code from which we started is reduced to

```java
if (u) {
  u2 = true;
}
u = true;
if (u2) {
  gp.devMode = !gp.devMode;
}
```

This is just a simplification of the code, while maintaining the same logic. In many places the logic can be simplified or changed as well.

Also, the code right now is very prone to errors appearing from simple typos. For example, to specify the direction of the motion you use strings. What happens if in one of the places you accidentally type "rigth" instead of "right"? The program will compile and run, but it will not work correctly and it can be very difficult to spot the error. Much better solution in such cases is to use enumerations. So, you create a new file Direction.java:

```java
public enum Direction {
  UP,
  DOWN,
  LEFT,
  RIGHT
}
```

Then in your Entity class you replace the declaration

```java
public String direction;
```

with

```java
public Direction direction;
```

When you need to use it you replace a string with the corresponding enumeration value, for example:

```java
switch(direction) {
    case Direction.UP:
            worldY -= speed;
            break;
    case Direction.DOWN:
            worldY += speed;
            break;
    case Direction.LEFT:
            worldX -= speed;
            break;
    case Direction.RIGHT:
            worldX += speed;
            break;
}
```

This is more efficient and less error-prone. If you make a typo and write `Direction.RIGTH`, then the code will not compile. The compiler can also warn you now if you forget to specify all the cases in your switch statement, etc.

There are many other places where improvements can be done (e.g. you consistently break encapsulation), but let's return to your main question about collisions. It's hard to tell from the information you provided, but I think the collision box for your player looks something like the red rectangle on the following picture:

[image]

Now, consider the player is a bit to the left and up of the door, and the player wants to move to the right:

[image]

In your code for collision detection you have the following:

```java
case "right":
       entityRightCol = (entityRightWorldX + entity.speed) / gp.tileSize;
       tileNum1 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityLeftCol] [entityTopRow];
       tileNum2 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityRightCol] [entityBottemRow];

       if(gp.tm.tile[tileNum1].hasCollision || gp.tm.tile[tileNum2].hasCollision)
       {
          entity.collisionOn = true;
       }
       break;
```

It says, that you calculate the position which is a bit to the right of the player's right side, and then check the left-top and the right-bottom tiles, i.e. tiles shown by green color on the previous picture. Do you see the problem now? You should check the **right**-top and the right-bottom tiles. However, because of your mistake the collision of the right-top corner with the wall is not detected and the player is allowed to move further, inside the wall.

Now you get this situation:

[image]

Let's say you press a down key now. The check is the following:

```java
case "down":
     entityBottemRow = (entityBottemWorldY + entity.speed) / gp.tileSize;
     tileNum1 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityLeftCol] [entityTopRow];
     tileNum2 = gp.tm.mapTileNum[entityRightCol] [entityBottemRow];

     if(gp.tm.tile[tileNum1].hasCollision || gp.tm.tile[tileNum2].hasCollision)
     {
         entity.collisionOn = true;
     }
     break;
```

You again check the left-top and the right-bottom corners. The right-bottom corner is free, but the left-top is stuck in the wall and you can't move. The same is true for all other directions except for movement to the left.

In order to fix this you need to check in each case the two tiles which are lying in the direction of the desired movement:

```
case UP:    check left-top and right-top;
case DOWN:  check left-bottom and right-bottom;
case LEFT:  check left-top and left-bottom;
case RIGHT: check right-top and right-bottom;
```